# How to get Oracle APEX Text Field value (now I get everything is NULL) (Oracle APEX Application Express 21.1)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created two Text Fields, `P1_MYTEXT_A` and `P1_MYTEXT_B`.

`P1_MYTEXT_A` has a change event.

- `Event: Change`,
- `Selection Type: Item(s)`,
- `Item(s): P1_MYTEXT_A`

Events that are True

- `Set Type: Static Assigment`,
- `Value: Set Type: Static Assigment`,
- `Value: ++&APP_ALIAS.++&P1_MYTEXT_A.++&APP_ID.++`

When entered in `P1_MYTEXT_A`, I wanted display `P1_MYTEXT_B` like this:

> ++TESTAPP01++AAA++106++

Instead, I get

> ++TESTAPP01++++106++

What do I should to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use static assignment, because - that's not exactly *static*. Set

- Action: Set Value
- Set Type: PL/SQL Expression
- PL/SQL Expression: `'++' || :APP_ALIAS ||'++'|| :P1_MYTEXT_A ||'++' || :APP_ID ||'++'`
- Items to submit: `P1_MYTEXT_A`

That's it.